# why we need address operator to access two dimensional string elements

Tags: c

why we need address operator to access two dimensional string elements whereas in case of simple array we need not.we just use subscript notation in case of simple array
for ex

```
char  masterlist[6][10] = {
       "akshay",
       "parag",
       "raman",
       "srinivas", 
       "gopal",
       "rajesh"
         };

printf("\nOriginal: %s %s", &names[2][0], &names[3][0] ) ;
```

whereas in case of array we just use

```
printf("%d",a[2][3]);
```

where a is an integer array.

Comment: You don't need the `&` **nor** the `[0]`.

Comment: Yeah, that solves it too.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simply because, when `printf` is invoked with `%s` as format specifier, it expects an argument of type `char *`, and not `char` which you would expect if you compare it to `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Format specifier `%s` is used to output strings - that is, sequences of characters - terminated with the null character `'\0'`.

If you have a two dimensional array with elements of type char, as in your example, then you can use the subscript operator:

```
char  masterlist[6][10] = {
       "akshay",
       "parag",
       "raman",
       "srinivas", 
       "gopal",
       "rajesh"
         };

printf("\nOriginal: %s %s", names[2], names[3] ) ;
```

Both `names[2]` and `names[3]` have type `char [10]` and represent character strings.

If you want to compare with an integer array when the following statement is used:

```
printf("%d",a[2][3]);
```

Then it outputs an element of the array. You could write the same way for the original character array:

```
printf("%c", names[2][3] ) ;
```

This statement would output character 'a' (if I am not mistaken).

If you want to output an entire character string instead of a single element of the array you have to use code I showed above.

Consider a simplified example. Let's assume there is a function

```
void f( const char s[10] );
```

This function declaration is equivalent to

```
void f( const char *s );
```

and the both declare the same one function.

That is an array passed as an argument to the function will be adjusted to a pointer to its first element. If you have an array

```
char s[10] = "Hello";
```

then these expressions are equivalent

```
f( s );
f( &s[0] );
```

The both pass a pointer to the first element of  the array.

Answer (score 0):

In the second `printf`, you print a single `int`. In the first `printf`, you print a string, i.e. `char` *array*.

Comment: OP says: "where `a` is an integer array".

Comment: `a` is, but `a[2][3]` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Because `names[2][0]` does not represent a string, it is a *character* from that string (in this case, the char `p`). `&names[2][0]` means "give me the address of the first character in that string", ie. the beginning of the string.

The language expects a pointer to a char as a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to print a string. In your 2-dimensional array you store strings. Even in the simple case where you had a string like `char *string="Hello";` you would print it like this:
    `printf("%s", string);` where string is a pointer. So when you want to print a string from an array you need to get the address of its first element.

Answer (score 0):

To print out an array of characters (a string) you need to provide the function with the first value of the array (index 0).

Therefore you are saying `&names[3][0]`, which basically returns the first element of the 4th array in the array `names`.

It's also equivalent to `names[3]` as they both point to the same place in the memory.